# How to ignore garbage values in serial communication between arduino and python

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, python, serial-data

I have `arduino uno`. I am trying to send and receive serial data from arduino to python. I have [usb to uart converter](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/49wAAOSw%7EXhZlUdj/s-l1200.jpg). I have connected its `tx` to `rx` of Arduino and `rx` to `tx` of Arduino and `gnd` is connected to `gnd`. I have connected this usb to my laptop where I have written below python script:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM6')

res = ser.read(10)
print(bytes.hex(res))
data = b"\x7E\x7E\xAA\x03\xAB\x77"
ser.write(data)

ser.close()
```

In above code, I am first reading the serial data, once the data is received, I sent out some hex packets. Below is the Arduino code:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  const byte message[] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03 };

  Serial.write(message, sizeof message);
  Serial.println("data sent");
  delay(1000);

  char buffer[6];
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    int size = Serial.readBytesUntil('\x77', buffer, 6);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) 
    {
      Serial.println(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
  }
}
```

In above code, I am first sending out the hex packets (which is received fine on python side) and then it waits for serial data. Once serial data is available to read, it reads it unitll `\x77` and prints out all data. This is received on serial console of Arduino:

[image]

You will notice that it has received the data but there are some extra `FF` being received. Why have we recived these `FF`. Also in the python code, we know we are sending data of length 6 so accordingly we have defined `char buffer[6]` in arduino but what if we have to receive data which we do not what length it will be. Please help. Thanks

Comment: How did you configure the serial port on the Python side? It is not done in the Python code itself.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Sorry I didn't get you by configuring the serial port. On the Python side, I have just mentioned the port number and thats it. About the hardware, its the same as mentioned in the question.

Comment: You cannot connect another USB-to-Serial converter on the same rx and tx pins. Serial ports cannot work in "parallel". Define a software serial using any other digital pins and connect your converter on those pins. The hardware rx and tx pins are already connected to the on-board "serial-to-USB" converter.

Comment: @Fahad I know and this is why when uploading the code, I need to remove the jumper wires rfom tx and rx pins. Once code is uploaded, I just press reset to start it again. Is that okay?

Comment: @SAndrew But you are still using the same pins for two serials! One is the onboard serial that you are watching on the Arduino IDE serial window (COM7) and one is in the python (COM6). That is a problem. Serials are not meant to be used as parallel buses.

Comment: @Fahad Thanks for your help. Using software serial is actually a good option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect that you see is [type promotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Type_promotion), in the C++ standard called "integral promotion", which happens implicitly. Values of type `char` are cast to `int`. Commonly, and in your case too, the `char` is by default signed.

The values `0xAA` and `0xAB` have a set most significant bit, which commonly designates a *negative* value in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). This holds true for your case. And so these negative values are cast to the same negative values, but in full width of an `int`. In your case, an `int` has 32 bits.

Hex `0xAA` as (by default signed) `char` is `-86` decimal. And `-86` decimal as (by definition signed) `int` is `0xFFFFFFAA` hex.

Printed as hex, all bits are shown. So you see all these `FF`.

The solution is to mask only the interesting lower 8 bits:

```cpp
    {
      Serial.println(buffer[i] & 0xFF, HEX);
    }
```

Comment: Good catch! Well, it's actually a bit more complicated: the `char` gets promoted to a 16-bit `int` by the overload resolution of `Serial.println()`, then explicitly [casted to `long` by `Print::print(int, int)`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.6/cores/arduino/Print.cpp#L79), then converted to `unsigned long` by the call to `printNumber()`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet This issue happens a lot with beginners, and I had it many times already. :-D -- Thanks for going deep into the details! I feel the official Arduino documentation in the web as unsatisfactory, because I always miss the exact and complete prototypes. We should not have to look into the library source...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea why some of the garbage and random values are being received? Thansk

Comment: @SAndrew Which garbage and random values do you mean? I don't see any. Please post a new question if this is a separate issue, else edit your question.